Upper bound for $\sum \tan(\theta/2)$ subject to condition that $\sum(\theta)\leq 2\pi$
I wish to find an upper bound of $\sum \tan(\theta_i/2)$ subject to condition that $k=\sum \theta_i\leq 2\pi$. We may also suppose that each $\theta_i$ is within the range $(0,\pi)$. Or, even better would be if I could do this with the range $(-\pi,\pi)$. Either would be helpful.
I have come across this sum while studying the measures of sets within a certain distance of boundaries of polygons or similar sets. Each $\theta$ represents the exterior angle at some vertex.
I've placed a hopelessly large bound on it by noting that it can be no more than $\tan(\theta_{max}/2)\cdot n$, where $n$ is the number of angles being summed. However, it's clear to me that as $\theta$ increases, $n$ decreases accordingly and the other terms cannot be as large. There is of course no general bound on this, as we can simply take $\theta_{max}$ to be arbitrarily close to $\pi$.
Moreover, there is no bound that can be placed on $n$. However, if $n$ is sufficiently large, then there can only be so many $i$ for which $\theta_{i}$ actually reaches the maximum value. The larger $n$ is, the smaller each angle must be due to our condition on $\sum \theta_{i}$.
I've also evaluated that this sum approaches $k/2\leq \pi$ as $\theta_{max}$ approaches zero. I believe this provides a lower bound, but I wish to find an upper bound in terms of $\theta_{max}$.

$\tan(x/2)$ is convex on $(0,\pi)$, which means that moving two inputs further apart will incresase the sum (that is, $\tan((x+\delta)/2) + \tan((x-\delta)/2)$ is an increasing function of $\delta$). It follows that the biggest we can make $\sum \tan(\theta_i/2)$ is by making as many of the $\theta_i$ equal to $\theta_{max}$ as possible, and then having one last leftover $\theta_i$ that's as large as possible.
